# is 'pip check' broken?

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I'm seeing this issue on two different computers today:

python functioning correctly, `pip check` returns no broken dependencies.

create virtualenv `virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/env` and `source ~/env/bin/activate`. all good

`pip check`: still no broken dependencies

as an example,`pip install six`:
`Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.10.0)`

`pip install jupyter` or `pip install catkin_pkg`, installation completes successfully, but:
`python-dateutil 2.7.2 requires six>=1.5, which is not installed.
catkin-pkg 0.4.1 requires pyparsing, which is not installed.`
ok weird, we just checked that six is installed, and at version 1.10, right?

gets weirder: `pip install six` again: 
`pip install six
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.10.0)
python-dateutil 2.7.2 requires six>=1.5, which is not installed.`

What? is it, or is it not installed?

Making sure users can read the dist-packages files with `sudo chmod -R go+rX /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` does not solve this.

At first I thought my system might have broken packages, but seeing this on two different machines is really weird.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this also happen in a clean virtualenv?

Comment: And which pip version? `pip --version`

Comment: do you mind precising what you mean by 'clean'? It happens every time I create a virtualenv and try, for example, pip install jupyter.

Comment: this also happens with a python 2 virtualenv, 
pip --version is  `pip 10.0.0b2 from /home/daniel/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)`

Comment: I've seen other cases where `pip` seems to be doing string compare of the version numbers instead of comparing the individual parts. I.e. `'1.5' > '1.10'` instead of `(1, 5) > (1, 10)`. It may just be a bug in `pip`. I don't see it reported at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting a few days, I upgraded pip, and the errors disappeared. It seems it was indeed a bug in pip version comparison, as described by [Erik Cederstrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219640/erik-cederstrand%20%22Erik%20Cederstrand)

Answer (score 0):

python-dateutil 2.7.2 requires six>=1.5, which is not installed

> from the error its clear that module six's version should be greater than v1.5

so just list out the installed version by `pip freeze`

As of now six have latest version you can install by

```
pip install six==1.11.0
```

Comment: the command above also shows that six 1.10 is installed. 1.10 is above 1.5, right?

Comment: might be numbers are not decimal convenction, so 1.11 can be greater than 1.5 so just try to install 1.11